# In java, how to check if a method m changed the state of its receiver

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to write a method which receives a serializable object (implements Serializable) o and a method m.
The method should compare the state of o before invoking m and after invoking m, and tell if invoking m changed o. It should check if the bits representing o were changed after the methods. Ho can I do it?

Comment: Before, you've asked the question you gave an answer, so bit unclear what are you looking for? Have you tried to implement comparison and got stack? Past a snippet of code here, we will try to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check at jguru, [you'll see a useful example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=103437):

> Wrap an ObjectOutputStream around a
>   ByteArrayOutputStream. Serializing an
>   object to the ObjectOutputStream will
>   then store the object in the byte
>   array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(myObject);
```

> To restore this object, reverse the
>   process:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais); 
Object myObject = ois.readObject();
```

If you compare the resulting byte arrays before and after the method is called, you'll be able to detect whether the object has been affected.

Answer (score 4):

First, correctly implement equals() (and hashCode()) on your object. You don't really need to serialize the object again. Just unserialize the original object and compare it (via equals()) to the object that you want to check for changes against.

I take it you mean:

```
public void checkChanged(Serializable o, Method m) { .... }
```

You can still do the above. Your assumption would be that the object o correctly implements equals() (and hashCode), which all objects SHOULD. You can (as other below have stated) compare the byte streams. It all depends on what you really mean by "changed".

Comment: I don't have a specific object. I am trying to write a method which recieves a serializable object (and a method). The method should compare the object's state before and after invokation using serialization. Could you help?

Comment: I'm not sure you right, since it has to work on any arbitrary object you cannot assume it has equals which can check the entire state of the receiver. So you do need to serialize.

Comment: @john, I was wondering what kind of help do you need? You do know what you suppose to do, so where the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to read and write your serialized objects and get their byte representations.  See details in [Testing object serialization](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-serialtest.html).

Answer (score 2):

Comparing to objects in Java is usualy made by calling equals() method. You can override this method to do the right comparison, then call it on instances before and after method call.

The other option is to compare the serialized representation of the objects

Comment: I edited the question. What I want to do is to compare the serialized representation of the objects (as you proposed). Can you explain how?

Comment: Convert to byte array and compare byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the serialized versions of an object, simply compare the byte arrays that the serialized objects create.

You won't be able to tell, necessarily, WHAT changed, but you will be able to tell that "something" changed.

Edit: How do you compare byte arrays?? Seriously?

```
public boolean same(byte b1[], byte b2[]) {
    if (b1.length != b2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {
        if (b1[i] != b2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I mean, how else do you do it? No magic wands here.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I need. But how can I "compare the byte arrays"?